# Methods for filtering within a Doctrine results Collection?

Tags: doctrine-orm

I'm very new to Doctrine, so this might seem a rather obvious question to those more experienced.

I'm writing a data import tool that has to check every row being imported contains valid data. For example, the Row has a reference to a product code, I need to check that there is a pre-existing Product object with that code. If not, flag that row as invalid.

Now I can easily do something like this for each row.

```
$productCode = $this->csv->getProductNumber();
$product = $doctrine->getRepository('MyBundle:Product')->findOneBy(array('code' => $productCode ));
```

But that seems hideously inefficient. So I thought about returning the entire Product Collection and then iterating within that.

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT p FROM MyBundle\Entity\Product p');
$products = $query->getResult();
```

All well and good, but then I've got to write messy loops to search for.

Two questions:

1). I was wondering if I'm missing some utility methods such as you have in Magento Collections, where you can search within the Collection results without incurring additional database hits. For example, in Magento this will iterate the collection and filter on the code property.

```
$collection->getItemByColumnValue("code","FZTY444");
```

2). At the moment I'm using the query below which returns an "rectangular array". More efficient, but could be better.

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT p.code FROM MyBundle\Entity\Product p');
$products = $query->getResult();
```

Is there a way of returning a single dimensional array without have to reiterate the resultset and transform into a flat array, so I can use in_array() on the results?

Answer (score 7):

If I understand your question correctly you want to filter an array of entities returned by getResult(). I had a similar question and I think I've figured out two ways to do it.

### Method 1: Arrays

Use the [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) method on your `$products` variable. Yes, this amounts to a "loop" in the background, but I think this is a generally acceptable way of filtering arrays rather than writing it yourself. You need to provide a callback (anonymous function in 5.3 preferred). Here is an example

```
$codes = array_filter($products, function($i) {
    return $i->getCode() == '1234';
});
```

Basically in your function, return true if you want the result returned into `$codes` and false otherwise (not sure if the false is necssary, or if a void return value is sufficient).

### Method 2: Doctrine's ArrayCollection

In your custom repository or where ever you are returning the getResult() method, you can instead return an ArrayCollection. This is found in the Doctrine namespace `Doctrine\Common\Collections\`.  More documenation on the interface behind this method can be found [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.3/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.Collection.html#_filter). So in this case you would have

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT p FROM MyBundle\Entity\Product p');
$products = new ArrayCollection($query->getResult());
```

You can then use the filter() method on the array collection. Use it in a very similar way to the array_filter. Except it doesn't need a first argument because you call it like this: `$products->filter(function($i) { ... });`

The ArrayCollection class is an iterator, so you can use it in `foreach` loops to your hearts content, and it shouldn't really be different from an array of your products. Unless your code explicitly uses `$products[$x]`, then it should be plug 'n' play*.

*Note: I haven't actually tested this code or concept, but based on everything I've read it seems legit. I'll update my answer if it turns out I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another hydration mode. $query->getResult() usually returns a result in object hydration. Take a look at $query->getScalarResult(), which should be more suitable for your needs.

More info on the [Doctrine 2 website](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#query-result-formats).

Comment: Hi Pierre.

$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT p.code FROM MyBundle\Entity\Product p');
$products = $query-> getScalarResult();

This returns a nested array with each member only containing a 'code' key. It seems odd that when only a single column is being returned that it creates a nested array.

None of the various hydration options seems to be able to return a single array containing just the values returned from the query...

Comment: You could write a custom hydrator. Seems like the cleanest approach to me.